# Tracking a Checkout Step con Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

Im trying to track the steps on an ecommerce site with Google Analytics, but for some reason Im not able to see the data on my checkout funnel.

I have this code:

```
$('#button_order_cart').click(function(e){
    var currencyId = currency.iso_code;
    for (var i=0; i < products.length ; i++ ){
        var product = products[i];
        console.log('PRODUUUCT', product);
        if(product.id_product === undefined){
            product.id_product = product.id;
        }
        ga('ec:addProduct', {
            'id': product.id_product,
            'name': product.name,
            'category': product.category,
            'price': product.price,
            'currency': currencyId,
            'quantity': product.quantity
        });

    }
    ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
        'step': 1,            // A value of 1 indicates this action is first checkout step.
    });

    // Check if we're logged in and automatically send checkout step step number 2.
    if(cart.id_customer !== null && cart.id_customer !== '0'){
        for (var i=0; i < products.length ; i++ ){
            var product = products[i];
            ga('ec:addProduct', {
                'id': product.id_product,
                'name': product.name,
                'category': product.category,
                'price': product.price,
                'currency': currencyId,
                'quantity': product.quantity
            });
        }
        ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
            'step': 2,           
            'option': 'Logged In'
        });
    }
});
```

And on the GA Debugging console Im getting this output when clicking the button:

```
VM7378 analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
VM7378 analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("ec:addProduct", {id: 1728, name: "24 Rosas - First Red", category: undefined, price: "Q. 348.00", currency: "GTQ", quantity: 2})
VM7378 analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
VM7378 analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 1})
```

Im not sure why I cant see the data if the Analytics debugging console throws no errors.

Can anyone help me verify if Im calling the right actions?

Comment: Are you sure enhanced ecommerce is enabled in GA?

Comment: do you have al the sheckout steps configured properly with the view settings as shown in p.3 here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-checkout ?

Comment: Yes I have both things configured, it looks like I had to send a pageview after the code in order to send the data. With the pageview added it all working now.